# How can I take 2 parameters as functions in Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I would like to define a list operation that takes a list and 2 functions as its input. Let me be more concise. This is the function I will implement.

This is the list I will use :

```
(define student-table '(students (name id gpa) (ali 1 3.2) (ayse 2 3.7)))
```

and I have defined some functions.

```
(define (get table row field)
 (nth (list-index field (cadr student-table)) row)
  )

(define (alter table row fields-values) 
  (cond
    ((= (length fields-values) 0) row)
    ((> (length fields-values) 0) 
       (list-with row (list-index (car (car fields-values)) (cadr student-table)) (cadr (car fields-values)))
       (alter table (list-with row (list-index (car (car fields-values)) (cadr student-table)) (cadr (car fields-values))) (cdr fields-values)))))
```

This is the function I would like to implement

```
(define (update-rows table predicate change))
```

So if I call with this, I would expect this result.

```
> (update-rows student-table
    (lambda (table row)
      (eq? (get table row 'name) 'ali))
    (lambda (table row)
      (alter table row '((gpa 3.3)))))
=> '(students (name id gpa) (ali 1 3.3) (ayse 2 3.7)))
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: I am trying to define a function which I gave its format with 3 parameters. One is a list, the other two are functions called predicate and change. So how do I define this function with these ?

Comment: The title says "How can I take 2 parameters as functions in Scheme?"  Are you trying to define a function with two arguments or three?  Based on your comment to @GoZoner's answer, it sounds like your question is actually along the lines of "how do I write a function that modifies a list passed into it?"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got most all of it.  Fill out `update-rows` something like this:

```
(define (update-rows table predicate change)
  ;; Look through all the rows
  (let looking ((rows (cddr table)))
    (unless (null? rows)
      ;; Handle the next row
      (let ((row (car rows)))
        (when (predicate table row)
          (change table row)))
      ;; Continue looking at the rest
      (looking (cdr rows))))
```

Comment: I understand the code in general. But it doesn't return anything. How can I modify it to return the changed list?

Comment: Oh, I assumed that your `alter` procedure destructively modified the table.  I guess you'll have to figure it out with my above code being 'something like' what you will need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to check if this works since I don't have `list-index` or `list-with`. I expect `change` to evaluate to a element that can replace the current row.

```
(define (update-rows table predicate change)
  (cons* (car table)  ; keep header 
         (cadr table) ; column symbols
         ;; process the rest
         (map (lambda (row)
                (if (predicate table row)
                    (change table row)
                    row))
              (cddr table))))
```

`cons*` is defined in R6RS. In some Scheme implementations (and Common Lisp) it's called `list*`